# Struggling to get rid of a black box on a template

Tags: html, css, joomla, templates

I'm pretty new to web design. I know more about the server side. I'm making a webcam website; www.camtheplanet.com. I'm working with a template in Joomla and I can't figure out how to get rid of a black box that's left, once I remove the logo. You can see what I'm talking about at the above URL. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that big black box across the entire site just below your navigation bar. That's a big graphic. To be exact that is being set in this file `http://camtheplanet.biz.tm/welcome/templates/themza_j15_11/css/blue.css`

Line `13`

ID `#page_bg: background: 
white url(../images/blue/bg_page.png) top repeat-x;`

If you delete the image using Chrome Developer tool you'll see this image is pretty big and also include the blue navigation bar.

The image is 1x920px and repeated. So it's a quick cheap, bad design because removing it means you'll have to redo some of the CSS, and HTML in the templates to keep your navigation bar background (blue color) and do the main bg area again.

Or change `page_bg` to `page_bg_1` and you'll have no black area. I just saw this ID which has just a thin black line below your blue navigation

Answer (score 0):

CSS

You will need to edit the background picture

```
#page_bg {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("../images/blue/bg_page.png");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

If you delete `background-image: url("../images/blue/bg_page.png");` you will see